# Hex string to int array conversion

Tags: java, string, hex

I am stuck with these problem that how to convert a hex string to unsigned byte array or an Integer array..

Please look in this example.

```
String s= "1f5621ff8963545a12152250"; //this is my hex string
```

i want to convert this string to an int array

```
int buff[]={0x1f,0x56,0x21,0xff,0x89,0x63,0x54,0x5a,0x12,0x15,0x22,0x50};
```

how could i do that...

thanks for help..

Comment: What have you tried? In your example it seems one can just split `s` every 2 chars and add `0x` in front of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One easy way: compute the length of your `int` array by dividing the length of the `String` by 2. Loop over the string, calling `substring()` to create the two-character strings "1f", "56", etc. Pass each string to `Integer.parseInt(string, 16)` (the second argument means that the argument is a hex string.) Store the results in the array as you compute them.

Comment: if i do Integer.parseInt("1f", 16) it compiled as 31 ... not in 0x1f

Comment: There is only one way to store an `int` internally; the representation as decimal or hexadecimal (or octal or whatever) numerals only happens on output. If you want to print an `int` in hexadecimal, then you have to specifically use `NumberFormat` or `printf()` or simply `Integer.toString(int, 16)` to display it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the string and every two elements of the string create the integer like this:

0Xmm, where mm are the two elements you've just scanned.

Then you increase the index of your array and keep iterating through the string and adding to the current "top" place of the array.