# String to Hex int array?

Tags: c#, .net

Is it possible to convert a HEX string to an integer array?

```
// This string...
string a = "8FCC44";

// Should look like this:
int[] b = {0x8f,0xcc,0x44};
```

But I don't have any idea how to do this.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9499389/hex-string-to-int-array-conversion) question, but i can't understand the answer. I am new to C#, so it would be nice if anybody could give me an example.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Using [MoreLINQ](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/wiki/OperatorsOverview) `a.Batch(2).Select(r => int.Parse(new string(r.ToArray()), NumberStyles.HexNumber))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer focuses on Java, but it is also possible to do this in C# in a similar way. Basicly you have to divide the string into substrings, each 2 characters long:

```
"8FCC44" -> "8F", "CC", "44"
```

You can do this using a `for` loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i += 2)
```

The loop variable `i` represents the start index of the current substring, this is why it always increases by 2. We can convert each substring using `Int32.Parse`:

```
Convert.ToInt32(a.Substring(i, 2), 16);
```

The last parameter represents the base of the source string (HEX = base 16).

Now we need an array to store the results. The size of the array can be calculated by the length of the string, divided by the length of each substring (= 2):

```
int[] b = new int[a.Length / 2];
```

To bring it all together your code could look like this:

```
string a = "8FCC44";
int[] b = new int[a.Length / 2];

for (int i = 0, int j = 0; i < a.Length; i += 2, j++)
    b[j] = Convert.ToInt32(a.Substring(i, 2), 16);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank sir,i just not solved,my problem,i learned well,from your answer,perfect explaintion thank you sir...

Answer (score 2):

```
int[] ConvertToIntArray(string a)
{
    List<int> x = new List<int>();
    for(int i=0; i<a.Length-1; i+=2)
        x.Add(int.Parse(a.Substring(i, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber));

    return x.ToArray();
}
```

You can then print them as Hex or Decimal using ToString() overloads of int (Int32) class.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `x.Add(int.Parse(a.Substring(i, 2), NumberStyles.HexNumber));`? I don't think using 16 will compile because `int.parse` doesn't have the equivalent overload to take an integer. You can use `16` if you're using `Convert.ToInt()`.

Comment: @keyboardP: You may be correct. I just wrote it quickly in SO, not VS. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

```
var a = "8fcc44";
var b = Enumerable.Range(0, a.Length / 2).Select(x => 
          Convert.ToInt32(a.Substring(x * 2, 2), 16)).ToArray();
```

Comment: @sll The hex values will always come in pairs.

Answer (score 0):

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string a = "8fcc44";            
            int itemNumber = 0;
            int[] iArray = new int[3];
            for (int i = 0; i < a.Length - 1; i += 2)
            {
                iArray[itemNumber] = (int.Parse(a.Substring(i, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber));
                itemNumber++;
            }
        }
```